# How to Create a Global Variable with a condition

Tags: java, global-variables

I want to create a global variable, but I want it to be one of two values, based on the machine's OS. I thought I could do this by writing the following code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class constants {
    public static String driverFile = null;
    public static String storageDirectory = null;
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")){
        storageDirectory = "C:\\Scripts\\Price_Tracker";
        driverFile = "geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64.exe";
    }else{//is linux
        storageDirectory = "/Price_Tracker";
        driverFile = "geckodriver-v0.27.0-linux64";
    }// end if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")

}//end public class constants
```

but I get an error saying " [Cannot resolve symbol 'getProperty'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRard.png) " , is what I'm trying to do even possible?

[image: Cannot resolve symbol 'getProperty']

Comment: You cannot just have a random floating if statement. It needs to be in a method or initializer block.

Comment: Look into a static initialization block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class constants {
    public static String driverFile = null;
    public static String storageDirectory = null;

    static {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")){
            storageDirectory = "C:\\Scripts\\Price_Tracker";
            driverFile = "geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64.exe";
        }else{//is linux
            storageDirectory = "/Price_Tracker";
            driverFile = "geckodriver-v0.27.0-linux64";
        }// end if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")
    }

}//end public class constants
```

Comment: thank you! I appreciate your help, I take it the if statement just needed to be in a method, like Michael had stated. thanks!

Comment: it's actually known as a static initializer. The static initializer runs once when the class is loaded into the JVM. The static initializer is all the code wrapped in the static {...} block.